# Encrypt file with BouncyCastle and only public key in C#?

Tags: c#, encryption, bouncycastle, pgp

New to PGP and I'm trying to encrypt a file through a C# console app. In my research it sounds as though BouncyCastle is one of the more popular ones to use. I found the following article and it looks like it would work just fine except that I only have the public key. 
http://burnignorance.com/c-coding-tips/pgp-encryption-decryption-in-c/

Looking around more, I have not found any examples where I can use just the public key to encrypt. All the examples I've come across want to use public key, private key, and password.

Comment: From my understanding the person decrypting needs the private key. In my case a different group will be decrypting so they need to have the private key and they give me the public key used to encrypt with. So, I only have the public key.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also new to working on PGP with C#, and I'd suggest using the PgpCore project, which makes working with Bouncy Castle easier.  There's a method to do exactly what you desire.  Something like this:

```cs
using (var pgp = new PGP())
{
    await pgp.EncryptFileAsync(@"C:\TEMP\unencrypted-input.txt", @"C:\TEMP\encrypted-output.pgp", @"C:\TEMP\public.asc");
}
```

See https://github.com/mattosaurus/PgpCore#encrypt for more options.

Answer (score 0):

I found a GitHub file that should get you VERY close to what you want. It gives you both the Encrypt (with public key) and Decrypt (with private key) methods. It uses the Bouncy Castle API, using the AES algorithm.

https://gist.github.com/dziwoki/cc41b523c2bd43ee646b957f0aa91943

Comment: Thanks. Looks like this is for RSA encryption which I believe is different than PGP but I'm still new with all of this so I don't know that 100%.

Answer (score 0):

The main way PGP is used, is where you encrypt with the receivers public key, and sign the message with your privat key.  Receiver can then decrypt with his privat key, and verify the signature with your public key. The password is used for the private key.

This setup is a designed decision taken when designing PGP, to live up to the name PGP - Pretty Good Privacy.

Comment: Ok, so just to confirm, I need to make my own private key and then when I encrypt I use their public key and my privatekey/password combination? I'm encrypting a file but I'm assuming it doesn't matter that it's a file versus and email message.

Comment: bit late but may help others, you always encrypt with a public key and only the person/system that has the private key can decrypt, when decrypting you decrypt your private key with your password and then you decrypt the data with your decrypted private key